# Trying to use toString to plot coordinates

Tags: java, keyboard

This is the description of my assignment but I'm stuck trying to use toStream. I don't want the answer but some guidance to the problem and using the Point class in Java. Thank you guys!

"Prompt the user for four integer values: x1, y1, x2, y2 that represent (x,y) coordinates for two points on the plane p1 and p2 respectively. Using the Point class from Java Class Library. Create two Point objects p1 and p2 with your input data, then print the data for both Point objects utilizing its toString method."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Point {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int x1, x2, y1, y2;

  System.out.println("Please enter your first X coordinate!");
  x1 = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Please enter your second X coordinate!");
  x2 = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Please enter your first Y coordinate!");
  y1 = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Please enter your second Y coordinate!");
  y2 = keyboard.nextInt();

 Point p1 = new Point();
 Point p2 = new Point();

 p1.toStream(x1,y1);
  }



}
```

Comment: do you want to use `toString` or `toStream`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the point objects to give them value and then simply print them out using `toString`, not `toStream`.

Below is code that should work for what you need to do, so stop reading here if you want to try it for yourself.

---

```
int x1, y1, x2, y2;

...

Point p1 = new Point(x1, y1), p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
System.out.println(p1);
System.out.println(p2); // You could use p1.toString() and p2.toString() here instead, but the println(Object o) already calls #toString() on the object.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I got this error when tring to compile though.  ERROR: constructor Point in class Point cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int